# How do i remove an item from a list and store it into a variable in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

so i want to remove an item from a list and store it into the variable at the same time in python. I tried a sample code like this:

```
rvals = []
rvals.append("row")
r = rvals.remove("row")
print(r)
```

but it turns out this doesnt really work and it gives r a NoneType value instead of removing what i wanted and storing it. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: rtfm: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range

Comment: rvals.pop(rvals.index("row"))

Comment: How about `print("row")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**list.remove(x)**

> Remove the first item from the list whose value is x. It is an error
>   if there is no such item.

So, as stated in the docs, you will not get the value returned.

**This can help:**

```
value = "row"

rvals = []
rvals.append(value)
print rvals.pop(rvals.index(value))
```

Or just use **pop()**, if you only want to remove and get the last inserted item:

```
value = "row"

rvals = []
rvals.append(value)
print rvals.pop()
```

**Output:**

```
row
```

Answer (score 0):

Printing a removed element from the list using remove() method generally results in None.
Hence, a better approach is to, first store the element to be removed and then remove it from the list.

Comment: Remove return None always, so "generally" does not fit here :).