# remove element in list and store in a variable in python

Tags: python

I wanted to remove an item from a list and store into a different variable but looks like remove updates the list and the assignment does not work. any work around for this?

```
>>> total_port = ['1/1/1','1/1/2','1/1/3']
>>> a = '1/1/3'
>>> b = total_port.remove(a)
>>> b
>>> total_port
['1/1/1', '1/1/2']
>>>
```

I tried going through the thread [How do i remove an item from a list and store it into a variable in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33849089/how-do-i-remove-an-item-from-a-list-and-store-it-into-a-variable-in-python) but this also does not help

Comment: Why doesn't that other question help?

Comment: `b = total_port.pop(total_port.index(a))`

Comment: Copy list beforehand `b = total_port[:]` and remove from copy. Not the most efficient way but simple.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Why do you think he needs to make a copy?

Comment: Read the documentation.  `remove` does not return any value, let alone the one removed.  That functionality is what `pop` does, which is outlined in the duplicate that you cited yourself.

Comment: @Barmar They mentioned "looks like remove updates the list" which I interpreted as surprising and unwanted behavior for them. Maybe I was wrong.

Comment: the soluction b = total_port.pop(total_port.index(a)) just stores the pop'ed item. my requrirement is to remove that element from the original list and return the remaining >>> total_port = ['1/1/1','1/1/2','1/1/3']
>>> a = '1/1/3'
>>> b = total_port.pop(total_port.index(a))
>>> b
'1/1/3'
>>>

Comment: @MichaelButscher He's just surprised that `b` doesn't get the removed value.

Comment: @VijaySwaminathan It does both. It removes it from the list and stores the removed item.

Comment: Why do you need to store the removed item? Just use `b = a`