# How to pop an element, in list using user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
cycles = ['hero','hercules']
user = input('enter pop cycle name \t')
cycles.pop(user)
print(user)
```

How do I remove an element based on a user input safely?

Comment: `pop()` works by index only. You will have to find the index to pop first.

Comment: `pop` expects an index, not a value.
Take a look at `remove` instead

Comment: What did you write for the `input`, and what is the error? Be specific and post the full error message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i remove an item from a list and store it into a variable in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33849089/how-do-i-remove-an-item-from-a-list-and-store-it-into-a-variable-in-python)

Comment: @Junkrat no that is permanent removal . I asking just pop up and store into another variable using user input

Comment: @kaya3 my question was, I want make pop() in the list,using user given value. And store that popped value into variable for further usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `remove()` instead of `pop()`, like so

```
cycles = ['hero','hercules']
user = input('enter pop cycle name \t')
cycles.remove(user)
print(user)
print(cycles)
stored_var = user
```

**note that if the element doesn't exist, it throws ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list exception.**

So, to safely remove an Item I'll suggest you to wrap the code with try and except

```
cycles = ['hero','hercules']
user = input('enter pop cycle name \t')

try:
  cycles.remove(user)
  print(user)
  print(cycles)
  stored_var = user

except:
  print("An exception occurred") 
  # handle it properly
```

Comment: But, need this element for further usage in program. So, how to pop and store this to variable?

Comment: @Rajadurai I edited the code, the var stored_var will have the variable that you need.

Comment: Wow thankyou so much its working now. I mean pop method not working with values it's right?

Comment: @Rajadurai To use the pop() function you must provide the index number, but you only have the item itself, so remove() is needed.

Answer (score 0):

remove is the method to use! not pop. see python documentation.

```
cycles = ['hero','hercules']
while(True):
    user = input('enter pop cycle name \t')
    try:
        cycles.remove(user)
    except ValueError:
    print("Your input is not exist in the list! try again .. ")
```